# Union in Sage/Python

Tags: python, sage

I have a list of lists (that might have any number of lists as entries) and want to find the union of this list (as a set) in Sage. I would think there is a short existing command already but I was not able to find it.

Here an example:

```
W=[[2, 1], [2], [3, 1], [1]]
T=W.union()
display(W)
display(T)
```

The desired output is T=[1,2,3] but it seems the command "union" does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use set().union()

```
W=[[2, 1], [2], [3, 1], [1]]
T=set().union(*W)
print(W)
print(T)
```

Comment: Thank you. But why do we need a star before the W?

Comment: @Mare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-and-doublestar-operator-mean-in-a-function-call  This explains it very well